# The original list is mutated after applying GA operators

Tags: python, python-3.x

The original list is mutated after applying GA operators
I am using the function below where I copy part of rankedChromos to `newpop` (list of lists) and then use a while loop to add remaining lists to it until the length of `newpop` is equal to the predetermined `popSize`. But for some reason, the `newpop` list is mutated after the while loop is implemented. In the while loop, I am trying to implement some GA operators and all I do is append the new individuals to the `newpop` list, which should not mutate the `newpop` but it does. Not just that, even the rankedChromos is mutated for some reason.

```
def nextGenPopulation (population, rankedPop, num_robots, crossover_rate):
    newpop = 0
    fitnessScores = [item[-1] for item in rankedPop ] # extract fitness scores                     
    rankedChromos = [item[0] for item in rankedPop ] # extract chromosomes 
    popSize = len(population)
    newpop = []
    print("\n fitness", fitnessScores)
    newpop.extend(rankedChromos[:int(popSize*0.4)]) # elitism
    print("newpop before operations", newpop)
    while len(newpop) < popSize:
        ind1, ind2 = selectFittest (fitnessScores, rankedChromos)
        ind1, ind2 = breed (ind1, ind2, num_robots, crossover_rate)
        newpop.append(ind1)
        newpop.append(ind2)
    print("\n newpop after operation", newpop)
    return newpop
```

For example if I am using 5 for popSize, the first 3 lists of newpop should remain the same before and after the implementation of the loop but it's not the same for some reason (example below) and I cannot understand why. I would very much appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
newpop before operation =  [[0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1], [1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2]]
newpop after operation =  [[0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1], [1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2], [0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1], [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Without reading the question, yeah, that's how python works. But there is a deepcopy utility somewhere in the python libraries. I'll read the question now and look up deepcopy in the docs in a minute.

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom Do you mean `from copy import deepcopy`?

Comment: As he tagged his question with python3.x I think he will need the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

Comment: We may also need a [mcve] with just enough info to call this and reproduce the result.

Comment: Could you also add `selectFittest` and `breed` or explain what they're doing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210180/discussion-between-just-learned-it-and-kenny-ostrom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newpop.extend(rankedChromos[:int(popSize*0.4)])` it is actually copying the references for the lists from `rankedChromos` for the first `int(popSize*0.4) - 1` lists into `newpop`, this means that any modification for `rankedChromos` for those lists will be reflected in `newpop`, most probably the function `selectFittest` it is mutating `rankedChromos` and as a result, you see the mutation in your variable `newpop`, you could use [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to eliminate this behaviour

```
from copy import deepcopy

newpop = deepcopy(rankedChromos[:int(popSize*0.4)])
```

---

here is an example to understand your issue:

```
list_1 = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]] # rankedChromos in your example
list_2 = [] # newpop in your example
list_2.extend(list_1[1: 3])
print('before operation',list_2)

# the function that mutates, selectFittest in your example
def some_fumction(l):
    for i in l:
        i[1:] = [-9]

some_fumction(list_1)

print('after operation',list_2)
```

output:

```
before operation [[2, 2], [3, 3]]
after operation [[2, -9], [3, -9]]
```

Comment: Thought it worked but when I ran it a few more times, it is doing the same thing again

Comment: Make sure to have the same input :) details matter

Comment: Do you mean the same value of input or same format? The value does change every time the new generation of the chromosome is generated. For the initial population, I am using a random generator that is run only at the beginning. The problem does not seem to happen every time `nextGenPopulation` is run but it does happen often.

Comment: I think I found my problem. The solution you presented was the correct one. I had just had to use `deepcopy()` in my main function as well. It is working properly now. Thanks a lot!